# are there some way to print by xps printer without show the save dialog?

Tags: printing, vb6, dialog, report

I'm trying to print by XPS PRINTER without the save dialog.

I'm using the Printer Object on VB6.

Any Idea?

Comment: Try the Printer.Print method to see if it sends the data directly to the default printer.

Comment: A default printer doesn't have to be an actual physical device. Depending on your computer, you might have the option to send documents as faxes, or to save them as PDF or XPS files when you print.

Comment: Yeah i know... but i've already using the Printer object to build my reports. I only need to hide the save dialog when the selected printer is a XPS Printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to control the XPS Document Writer file name from VB6, but it is possible using a third party product named [Win2PDF](http://www.win2pdf.com).  To [set the XPS file name](http://www.win2pdf.com/doc/specifyinganoutputfilename.htm) in Win2PDF, you use the SaveSetting method to save the file name to the registry as in:

```
SaveSetting "Dane Prairie Systems", "Win2PDF", "PDFFileName", "c:\test\test.xps"
```

After calling SaveSetting with the key set to "[PDFFileName](http://www.win2pdf.com/doc/specifyinganoutputfilename.htm)", you print to the Win2PDF printer using the VB6 printer object to create the XPS file.